# CDATA parsing in blackbery10

Tags: blackberry-10

I am new to blackberry 10 platform I am stuck with XML CDATA parsing . I am currently using QXMLSTREAMREADER and it is efficient to get the attributes but not getting CDATA. The Xml I used is
as follows

```
<message_list>
    <message title = "title1" date = "21-08-2012 10:20">
        [CDATA[ Sample data here ]]
    </message>

    <message title = "title2" date = "21-08-2012 10:20">

        [CDATA[Sample data here]]
    </message>

</message_list>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use custom class extend from QXmlDefaultHandler and can parse CDATA there

Comment: yes I tried this and parsed CDATA in blackberry10. thanks for your reply.